# click to messenger facebook adcreative with page_welcome_message example has issues

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to execute the sample curl script that lets you create a click to messenger adcreative with a welcome message. https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2018/03/20/click-to-messenger-ads/
But the object_story_spec thats provided in the example generates an error while executing. Please, can anyone help?

Following is the Curl script(copied from the above link) has issues:

```
                           'title':'Start Chatting',
                        'payload':'USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD'
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      'quick_replies':[  
         {  
            'content_type':'text',
            'title':'Hello',
            'payload':'reply1'
         },
         {  
            'content_type':'text',
            'title':'Learn More',
            'payload':'reply2'
         }
      ]
   }
}"},"page_id": "369499770162312" }' \-F 'access_token=EAADxqKWGDYkBAEZCwo0xa1sQG8LGitmaGtAHp4mfWtwvY27m6xGYPImPnvzPPT8ZAw9pPljFwfhC2DZAYuqMXBD6TZA4yGf1lsh9uUjCYsGr47GpmHZAVajsDdSZCb3GLVKSTmR5fID9eVu9S2HBkeZBRJWZAYxNN6dOz4mRVI4iZCQZDZD' https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/act_210261016055454/adcreatives
```

Comment: Are you running it as shown in your question? If so you're missing a lot of the curl request

Comment: Umm you just published your access token. I've tried to edit it away but my edit of your post requires moderation/approval. I suggest you XXXXXX it out right away.